# How to display HTML-formatted output files in Travis?

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, travis-ci

I'm trying to deploy an Android library on Bintray using Travis-CI. But when I upload my repo... I got this:

Ran lint on variant release: 6 issues found

```
Ran lint on variant debug: 6 issues found

Wrote HTML report to file:///home/travis/build/leandroBorgesFerreira/MoreCLoseButton/app/build/outputs/lint-results-debug.html

Wrote XML report to file:///home/travis/build/leandroBorgesFerreira/MoreCLoseButton/app/build/outputs/lint-results-debug.xml

:app:lint FAILED
```

Normally I would go to my project out put and read the lint-results-debug.html... But I don't know how to access this file in Travis.

So, **How can I access outputs/lint-results-debug.html in Travis??**

Any help is welcome!

**Edit**

my .travis.yml:

```
language: android
jdk: oraclejdk8
sudo: false

addons:
  apt:
    packages:
      - lynx

android:
  components:
  - platform-tools
  - tools
  - build-tools-25.0.0
  - android-25
  - extra-android-m2repository
script: 
  - if [ -f /home/travis/build/leandroBorgesFerreira/MoreCLoseButton/app/build/outputs/lint-results-debug.html ]; then lynx -dump /home/travis/build/leandroBorgesFerreira/MoreCLoseButton/app/build/outputs/lint-results-debug.html; fi
  - ./gradlew -PbintrayUser="${bintrayUser}" -PbintrayKey="${bintrayKey}" build
  bintrayUpload --stacktrace --info
env:
  global:
  - secure: [...]
  - secure: [...]
```

Comment: Sorry for asking here but I have spent a lot of time looking a good way to build a file like yours (using bintrayUpload). Do you have any link in where I can find more information how to do it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `lynx -dump` to dump a plain-text rendering of any HTML file output from a Travis run.

To make Travis install `lynx -dump`: To the top of your `.travis.yml`, add this:

```
addons:
  apt:
    packages:
      - lynx
```

Assuming the HTML file is an error log of some kind, you can make Travis show the output by putting something like the following in the `script` part of your `.travis.yml`:

```
after_failure:
  - if [ -f /home/travis/build/…/foo.html ]; then lynx -dump /home/travis/build/…/foo.html; fi
```

Comment: I have this:

script: 
  - if [ -f /home/travis/build/leandroBorgesFerreira/MoreCLoseButton/app/build/outputs/lint-results-debug.html ]; then lynx -dump /home/travis/build/leandroBorgesFerreira/MoreCLoseButton/app/build/outputs/lint-results-debug.html; fi
  - ./gradlew -PbintrayUser="${bintrayUser}" -PbintrayKey="${bintrayKey}" build
  bintrayUpload --stacktrace --info

But now I got: syntax error: (<unknown>): could not find expected ':' while scanning a simple key at line 20 column 3

Comment: What is on line 20 of your `.travis.yml` file? Can you maybe post a copy of your `.travis.yml` file in the question?

Comment: I put the .travis.yml in the question now

Comment: It seems like that `.travis.yml` file has a line break after `build` and before `bintrayUpload --stacktrace --info`? If so there should be no line break there—it should all be on one line.
`

Comment: Yes, you are right... that was stupid, sorry about that. I'm running the travis right and I let you know if the dump worked

Comment: The script ran. But I didnt see any change in the console... The lint was written in file:///home/travis/build/leandroBorgesFerreira/MoreCLoseButton/app/build/outputs/lint-results-debug.html

Comment: I think you need to swap order of the two lines in the script section, right? So that the line that starts with `./gradlew -PbintrayUser="${bintrayUser}" ` comes first. That’s the line the causes the lint to run, isn’t it? So after that runs, **then** there’s an `outputs/lint-results-debug.html` file for `lynx` to read. But before the `./gradlew -PbintrayUser="${bintrayUser}" …` part runs, there is no `outputs/lint-results-debug.html` file, so currently that `if…then` never invokes `lynx`, because it finds no `outputs/lint-results-debug.html` file.

Comment: Now I got: 

The command "if [ -f /home/travis/build/leandroBorgesFerreira/MoreCLoseButton/app/build/outputs/lint-results-debug.html ]; then lynx -dump /home/travis/build/leandroBorgesFerreira/MoreCLoseButton/app/build/outputs/lint-results-debug.html; fi" exited with 127.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/129855/discussion-between-sideshowbarker-and-leandro-borges-ferreira).

Answer (score 4):

While sideshowbarker gave a generic answer, I'd like to point out that Android lint has an [option for console output](https://google.github.io/android-gradle-dsl/current/com.android.build.gradle.internal.dsl.LintOptions.html#com.android.build.gradle.internal.dsl.LintOptions:textReport), so you can do this in your build.gradle:

```
android {
    lintOptions {
        textReport = true
        //textOutput "stdout" // default location, perfect for travis
    }
}
```

Which removes the need for an extra dependency, and an extra script; plus it's reproducible on local machine easily.

One can take this a step further (in case spamming console on local machine is to be avoided) and do

```
android {
    lintOptions {
        textReport = project.property("lint.output.console").toBoolean()
    }
}
```

and in `gradle.properties`: `lint.output.console=false`

and in `.travis.yml`: `gradlew -Plint.output.console=true build`